# Friconix integration in web page

Tags: javascript, icons, cdn

I try to integrate an icon library (Friconix) on a web page by following instructions on this [Quick start guide](https://friconix.com/start/#get-friconix).

I do not understand why icons are not displayed. I made a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3p1k2fay/

```
<html>
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/js/friconix.js"></script>
</html>
<body>
  <i class="fi-xnsuxl-setting"></i>
  <i class="fi-xwsuxl-reload fi-spin"></i>
</body>
```

I can't figure out why it is not functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right link according to [this page](https://friconix.com/start/#get-friconix)

friconix.com/**js**/friconix.js

instead of

friconix.com/**cdn**/friconix.js

I updated your jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/431dbf0w/

```
<html>
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/cdn/friconix.js"></script>
</html>
<body>
  <i class="fi-xnsuxl-gear"></i>
  <i class="fi-xwsuxl-reload fi-spin"></i>
</body>
```

Et voila !

::: EDIT :::

The best option is to create custom boards that are lighter than loading the whole JS file.

Comment: Simplest mistake are sometime the hardest to solve.